# Split an array based on the value of another array

Tags: php, arrays

OK, so I would like to create a multi dimensional array for a given array based on the values in another array.

I have an array like this:

```
"coordinatesArray" => array(
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:17 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.787229","longitude"=>"144.940128","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:18 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.789705","longitude"=>"144.942424","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:19 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.792537","longitude"=>"144.946029","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:20 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.795487","longitude"=>"144.949891","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:21 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.797302","longitude"=>"144.951930","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:22 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.799319","longitude"=>"144.954419","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:23 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.800879","longitude"=>"144.956372","speed"=>"0.0")
)
```

and another array like this:

```
"coordinatesSplitMarkerArray" => array(
    array("latitude"=>"-37.789705","longitude"=>"144.942424"),
    array("latitude"=>"-37.799319","longitude"=>"144.954419")
)
```

I would like to split the first array at the positions given in the second array essentially creating 3 arrays with the values from the first array that fall within the split values.

So the output should be:

```
"coordinatesArray" => array(
    array(
        array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:17 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.787229","longitude"=>"144.940128","speed"=>"0.0"),
    ),
    array(
        array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:18 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.789705","longitude"=>"144.942424","speed"=>"0.0"),
        array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:19 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.792537","longitude"=>"144.946029","speed"=>"0.0"),
        array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:20 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.795487","longitude"=>"144.949891","speed"=>"0.0"),
        array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:21 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.797302","longitude"=>"144.951930","speed"=>"0.0"),
    ),
    array(
        array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:22 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.799319","longitude"=>"144.954419","speed"=>"0.0"),
        array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:23 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.800879","longitude"=>"144.956372","speed"=>"0.0")
    )
)
```

Hope that makes sense to someone.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried anything? yes? then show us

Comment: Just found a much easier way. Instead of storing a corresponding lat/lng values I will just store the position at which the array should be split. Thanks for looking though.

Comment: Great to hear that.Sounds good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

```
<?php
$coordinatesArray = array(
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:17 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.787229","longitude"=>"144.940128","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:18 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.789705","longitude"=>"144.942424","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:19 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.792537","longitude"=>"144.946029","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:20 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.795487","longitude"=>"144.949891","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:21 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.797302","longitude"=>"144.951930","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:22 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.799319","longitude"=>"144.954419","speed"=>"0.0"),
    array("altitude"=>"88.9201049804688","dateAdded"=>"2016-10-19 09:04:23 +1000","latitude"=>"-37.800879","longitude"=>"144.956372","speed"=>"0.0")
);


$coordinatesSplitMarkerArray = array(
    array("latitude"=>"-37.789705","longitude"=>"144.942424"),
    array("latitude"=>"-37.799319","longitude"=>"144.954419")
);

$data = array();
$new = 0;
$splitMarker = 0;
foreach($coordinatesArray as $i=>$value){
    if($coordinatesSplitMarkerArray[$splitMarker]['latitude'] == $coordinatesArray[$i]['latitude'] && $coordinatesSplitMarkerArray[$splitMarker]['longitude'] == $coordinatesArray[$i]['longitude']){
        $new++;
        if(count($coordinatesSplitMarkerArray)-1>$splitMarker){
            $splitMarker++;
        }
    }
    $data[$new][] = $coordinatesArray[$i];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: good logic. +1 from my side . just one correction `$i<count($coordinatesArray);` take the count outside of the loop (count it first and assign it to a variable and use that variable into loop). That will be more eligent

Comment: Thank You, I changed the for loop for foreach.

Comment: even more accurate and sound logic. Good